# Adding a fence on top of a wall

Tags: planning-permission

I am looking at adding a Fence to the side of the yellow wall to go up about 3 foot.  will i need to get planing permission or can i just go ahead, the yellow building is mine?

[image]

Comment: This question can only be answered by your local zoning/planning board.

Answer (score 1):

> **Adding a [3 foot] fence *on top of* a wall**

That wording and picture suggest a UK location.

It isn't clear to me where exactly you intend to put this fence but if you are adding 3 foot to the height of a wall you are very likely to need planning permission.

The only exception would be if the existing wall is less than 3 foot and is not a boundary wall.

The Governments [planning portal](https://www.planningportal.co.uk/info/200130/common_projects/20/fences_gates_and_garden_walls) says

> You will need to apply for planning permission if you wish to erect or add to a fence, wall or gate and:
>
> - it would be over 1 metre high and next to a highway used by vehicles (or the footpath of such a highway); or over 2 metres high elsewhere; or
> - your right to put up or alter fences, walls and gates is removed by an article 4 direction or a planning condition; or
> - your house is a listed building or in the curtilage of a listed building.
> - the fence, wall or gate, or any other boundary involved, forms a boundary with a neighbouring listed building or its curtilage.

Comment: yes this is in the UK, and what i am looking to do is fix a 6 foot fence panel so that the highest point of the roof is where the right hand corner will be for the fence panel. hope this make sense.